# Deal with javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php, symfony-panther

I started to play with panther since 2 days, awesome tool, but I've a little problem with a scenario.

I want to delete a article from my app.
The process is the following : 
I press a button, an alert shows up to confirm.

Problem is the WebDriver throws a `UnexpectedAlertOpenException`
ok so I add this to the client `$client->getWebDriver()->switchTo()->alert()->accept();`

but now I got a `NoAlertOpenException`: no alert open, immediatly after this line.

I'm embarrassed

here is my test :

```php
public function testDeleteAnArticle()
    {
        $client = static::createPantherClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

        $crawler = $this->loginAs($client, $crawler, 'admin', 'azerty');

        $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Dashboard')->link());
        $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('ARTICLES')->link());

        $client->getWebDriver()->switchTo()->alert()->accept(); //<-- it will throw a NoAlertOpenException

        $crawler = $client->click($crawler->filter('a.is-danger')->eq(5)->link());

        $client->waitFor('.notification');

        $this->assertContains('The article has been successfully deleted', $crawler->filter('.notification')->text());
    }
```

Someone knows how to deal with this ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the *NoAlertOpenException* exception is thrown there is simply no alert open, so panther can't close one.

You can run your tests headless with the environment variable *PANTHER_NO_HEADLESS* set to 1. Then you can see what is really going on. Maybe your test is just clicking on the wrong link.

Please note, that after accepting the alert you need to re-instantiate the $crawler. You can do this by reloading the page with:

```
$crawler = $client->reload();
```